# my own inventory in ansible

Tags: ansible

i created my own inventory and added 2 ip address out of 3 ip addresses , but when running below command getting error , please advise ?

```
ansible all -i myinventory -m command -a 'Free'
```

Error :

```
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Distribution Ubuntu 18.04 on host 172.31.35.222 should use /usr/bin/python3, but is using /usr/bin/python for
backward compatibility with prior Ansible releases. A future Ansible release will default to using the discovered platform python for this
host. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more information. This feature will be
removed in version 2.12. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
172.31.35.222 | FAILED | rc=2 >>
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Distribution Ubuntu 18.04 on host 172.31.37.140 should use /usr/bin/python3, but is using /usr/bin/python for
backward compatibility with prior Ansible releases. A future Ansible release will default to using the discovered platform python for this
host. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more information. This feature will be
removed in version 2.12. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
172.31.37.140 | FAILED | rc=2 >>
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

i tried to change deprecation_warnings setting in ansile.cfg but still getting this error

Answer (score 1):

`Free` is not a valid command, but `free` is. Simple typo!

Try this:

```
ansible all -i myinventory -m command -a 'free'
```

You do not even need to specify the command module (for linux):

```
ansible all -i myinventory -a 'free'
```

Comment: done , got it , thanks ,it worked